# Android Kotlin - Volley set POST Parameters in JsonArrayRequest

Tags: android, kotlin, android-volley

This is the code:

```
val requestQueue: RequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this@MainActivity)

val jsonArrayRequest = JsonArrayRequest(
    Request.Method.POST,
    "$domain/do_getmemes.php",
    null,
    Response.Listener { response ->

    },
    Response.ErrorListener { // Do something when error occurred

    }
)

requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest)
```

and I just want to add some Parameters!

I've seen this JAVA example: https://gist.github.com/mstfldmr/f6594b2337e3633673e5

but I don't know what/where/how to add the parameters from this abomination of example.

I tried to add this part right after `JsonArrayRequest()`:

```
  {
    @Override
    protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
      Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
      params.put("user","YOUR USERNAME");
      params.put("pass","YOUR PASSWORD");
      return params;
    }
    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
      Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
      params.put("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
      return params;
    }
  }
```

but it doesn't get converted to Kotlin.

I need to send some Ints and Strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add object so you can override functions

```
val jsonArrayRequest = object : JsonArrayRequest(
    Request.Method.POST,
    "$domain/do_getmemes.php",
    null,
    Response.Listener { response ->

    },
    Response.ErrorListener { // Do something when error occurred

    }
) {
    override fun getBody(): ByteArray {
        val parameters = HashMap<String, String>()
        parameters["key"] = "value"
        return JSONObject(parameters.toString()).toString().toByteArray()
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't get any errors but it doesn't send any POST values. The PHP code on the server: file_put_contents('req.txt', $_POST['key']); creates an empty req.txt file instead of "value" in it

Comment: have you tried ur api with postman? was it successful?

Comment: Postman? I normally use loopj AsyncHttpClient for this api but it doesn't work with older Android versions with ssl. I already made a question because of that and try to use volley as alternative

Comment: postman is a tool for testing api request. you might want to create a simple php to catch a value from a key to check your volley request is passing a value or not.

Comment: well I did: file_put_contents('req.txt', $_POST['key']); I always test APIs when using loopj like that. Besides I get "Redundant overriding method" on override fun  in override fun getHeaders() and when I remove override then: "'getHeaders' hides member of supertype 'JsonArrayRequest' and needs 'override' modifier" smh.. I loathe Android

Comment: maybe change ur php file to get value from **php://input** not from $_POST. because volley send as jsonobject, i have tried the code to hit post api in `http://dummy.restapiexample.com/` with route `/create` and it worked

Comment: jsonobject would also be ok how can I get it in PHP file? I don't know what you mean by php://input. Unfortunately I must go now I will get back here in couple hours

Comment: [reference for you](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-receive-json-post-with-php/)

Comment: I tried this now: $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($json);
file_put_contents('req.txt', $data); but still the file is empty

Comment: Should be $data->key

Comment: Ok it works thanks! Since sending normal POST is apparently impossible I'll accept this alternative ofc :)

Comment: I recommend you to use retrofit2