# Android Kotlin Volley - Upload FILE InputStream along with POST parameters

Tags: android, kotlin, file-upload, android-volley, inputstream

I need to upload files to server that are either jpeg or gif.

So far I use loopj AsyncHttpClient and there it's easy as always with this beautiful library:

```
val params = RequestParams()
params.put("userid", prefs!!.getLong("userid", 0))
params.put("file", finalInputSteam)
```

but I can't use it for older Android APIs when the url is https.

So how to do this with volley? Anything other than loopj seems to be complete crap that often needs workarounds (example: [Android Kotlin - Volley set POST Parameters in JsonArrayRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62461515/android-kotlin-volley-set-post-parameters-in-jsonarrayrequest)) and very poor documented :/

This is what I have so far:

```
    val request = object: StringRequest(
        Method.POST,
        "$domain/upload.php",
        Response.Listener<String> {
            finish()
        }, Response.ErrorListener { volleyError ->

        })
    {
        override fun getParams(): MutableMap<String, String> {
            val parameters = HashMap<String, String>()
            parameters["userid"] = prefs!!.getLong("userid", 0).toString()
            parameters["file"] = finalInputSteam!!
            return parameters
        }
    }

    val rQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this@UploadImage)
    rQueue.add(request)
```

I get an error because `finalInputSteam` is `InputStream` instead of `String` so how to do this??

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39703655/how-to-upload-image-on-server-using-volley)?
That link shows you how to do it, also, I recommend you using Retrofit2.